# Is there any confidential information held in a SAMLRequest?

Tags: saml

Do I need to be particularly careful not to leak a SAMLRequest? My instincts are telling me no, since it's just the request... but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAML Request usually does not contain any confidential information. But it can include the identity of a user in the `<saml:Subject>` element. Depending on context that could be said to be confidential.

There is also an option to include the response return location - which in SAML2 lingo is called "Assertion Consumer Service" or ACS. That is just a URL to the application so it is not confidential (unless someone encodes confidential information in that URL, but why?). But, making sure the response is not sent to someone else the using dynamic ACS from the AuthnRequest requires the AuthnRequest to be protected by a signature.

Answer (score 1):

A SAML request doesn't contain any sensitive/confidential information. It only contains the information about the SP url and relay state information.

A signed SAML request will additionally contain a hashed signature value along with the public key for the SP.