# App Store Connect message: Your account will soon need to be migrated to federated auth

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am getting this message on my App Store Connect:

> Your account will soon need to be migrated to federated auth. You can start the process now or wait until August 28, 2020 for your account to be migrated automatically.

[image]

If I click on "Start the process now", then getting this:

```
{"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"error":["Not Found"],"info":null},"statusCode":"ERROR"}
```

And when I click on "Learn More", Safari can't open the page for me. It is giving this:

[image]
[image]

So can any of you please tell me what is this all about?

Comment: Thanks, this really looks like a mistake by apple. Two broken links and not much more information... weird!

Comment: Strangely there's not a single post on internet regarding this! Which was more wired to me. :/

Comment: Probably because they *just* accidentally released something or toggled the wrong switch. There is already a second SO question regarding this (linked) meaning you are not alone (and a lot of upvotes on this q). I guess it will either be fixed to have proper links in the coming hours or the warning will be removed entirely.

Comment: Just wanted to warn you about the "Safari Can't find this page" screen shot you've shared. This contains some kind of token, I don't know what it's used for but it seems to be some kind of SSO authentication token. Be careful what you share.

Comment: @JeffreyLanters I thought the same thing and checked: it appears to be a SAML request and those typically do not contain any sensitive information ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111061/is-there-any-confidential-information-held-in-a-samlrequest )

Comment: In the morning while I was posting this I hadn't the slightest idea that this question is going to be as popular where it will get 100+ upvotes and more than 5k+ views within 10 hours. I got more than 10 emails from different people asking about this and that. Thanks for all of your support and suggestions. I hope nothing bad happens to anyone. And Kudos to Apple's support, It just likes having a build on Xcode after cleaning the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it was a bug. Right now when I log in to my App Store Connect, I am not seeing any related error or message on the top portion of my portal. It simply got vanished.

[image]

Comment: Well, that is what was expected. They got the message and backtracked, instead of this support BS they gave previously suggesting to "just ignore it". Good to see.

Comment: Exactly. They didn't acknowledge that it was a bug on their platform. Just technically told us to avoid it. Which is, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Yes it's true the message have disappear, guess our complains finally get the point.

Answer (score 45):

Looks like broken deploy on Apple’s end where they accidentally rolled out an internal page to third-party developers. AppleConnect and Quip are used internally so it’s not surprising to see them mentioned. (The link that is failing to load is behind Apple’s corporate VPN.)

Answer (score 15):

I have contacted Apple Support on phone and they assure me that it is not for developers accounts and I should just ignore it as it is related to Apple Business Manager. And as a confirmation they sent an e-mail to confirm it with some links to help with understanding more about it.

https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/apple-business-manager/intro-to-federated-authentication-apdb19317543/web

[image]