# Your account will soon need to be migrated to federated auth

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer-account

I have received this message from Apple on AppStore connect, what does that mean?

[image]

When we click learn more or start the process now,
It takes us to another webpage

[image]

and when we go for login, the site is not reachable

[image]

Tried on Safari and Chrome

Comment: I believe this question has not much to do on StackOverflow, maybe check the guide to [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does "Learn More" tell you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500312/your-account-will-soon-need-to-be-migrated-to-federated-auth-app-store-connect

Comment: @NojaRelamschtz
I tried, "Learn More"
Then it takes to another page and then apple site is not reachable

Comment: @luk2302, edited details, the site is not reachable

Comment: You can ignore this message